# Google play in-app product price does'nt change

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play, in-app-billing, soomla

I am developing a mobile game for Android using Unity 3D. I'm using Soomla package as the in-app billing module.

Now, I only have one item to sell. The initial price for that item was X, and I have changed it to Y (days ago) in the google play developer console inside the in-app products sector. But, the price still showing as X inside the app in the google play purchase window when trying to purchase it. The Soomla code also contains the Y price-

```
 public static VirtualGood NO_ADS_LTVG = new LifetimeVG(
        "No Ads",                                                       // name
        "No More Ads!",                                                 // description
        "no_ads",                                                       // item id
        new PurchaseWithMarket(NO_ADS_LIFETIME_PRODUCT_ID, <Y price>));     // the way this virtual good is purchased
```

The app is in production, the in-app item in the google play console is active, the apk was built as release mode, Soomla code of purchasing and viewing the balance is good, but the price is still X.

Any idea?

By the way, does any one know what's the purpose of the pricing in the `PurchaseWithMarket` object? as far as I understand the price is defined by the in-app item inside the google developer console, and no further information about that is availble in the Soomla documentation.

Comment: Google Play doesn't propagate changes instantly. Cleare data pf Google Play Services on the device can help.

Comment: The price in the PurchaseWithMarket object is for times of no connectivity. Like a backup plan to show the user the price if the internet connection is down. That is all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the price from your google play developer console, i do no think it is possible from the in app.

IF you have enabled in app billing sucessfully, then follow these instructions.

1.) Log in to your google play dev console.

2.)Select your app

3.)Then select your in app products(2nd half left side)

4.)Create/Edit your in app product.(Existing product)

5.)Go to Pricing section.

6.)Enter the default price and select `Overwrite existing prices` checkbox, then press auto convert prices

7.)Press the blue save button.

Over